# Remove IIS Binding For SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration, iis

I have a SharePoint 2013 site that has two port 80 bindings in IIS: one with a host name, one without (IP addresses are unassigned in both bindings).  I would like to remove the port 80 binding that does not have a hostname.

What is the recommended way to do this: delete the binding in IIS, or through SharePoint Central Admin?

Comment: what had your AAM settings tells? is there any reason why you have both bindings?

Comment: The site originally did not have a host name.  To add a host name, I launched Central Admin, and unextended the application from IIS.  I then reextended the application, providing the host name.  It looks like IIS created a new port 80 binding with the host name, and kept the orignal port 80 binding without the host name, instead of updating the original binding.  In AAM, I have only one URL for the default zone.

Comment: So basically you extend the web application? if yes in which zone?

Comment: Yes, I extended the application, to the default zone.

Comment: default zone automatically created but you can extend to other 4 zones(intranet, the internet,custom,extranet)..I think you recreated the web app in default zone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no recommended way to delete the IIS bindings because it depends upon you environment configuration. As per your settings, I think you can do this.

- Remove the extra binding, as you are using the Hostname then keep that one.

From your comment, I think it is better if you delete the web application, make sure sites gone from IIS. Then recreate the web application. Dont delete the content Database, you can use it again.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So, when you say "it is better if you delete the web application, make sure sites gone from IIS", do you mean selecting "Yes" under "Delete IIS web sites", after selecting "Remove SharePoint from IIS web site"?

Comment: After reading you statement, i think if things are really mess up then it is better to re create it. after performing that in Central admin, make sure IIS also remove it.

Comment: Nothing's messed up. The SharePoint site is working fine.  It's just that I have two bindings in IIS for a SharePoint site that are bound to port 80, and I want to remove one (the one without the host name).

Comment: ok then do it and test after that.

Comment: I just removed the unwanted binding in IIS, and the site conitnues to works fine, even after doing an IIS reset, as well as stopping/starting  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service in Central Admin. I've confimed that there is now only one binding.  If the other binding suddenly resurfaces, I will try the other solution: Unextending it and removing the site in Central Admin, and then reextending the site.

Comment: I think you will be fine, as you did good testing